# I wonder why WebSecurity.Login(username,password) returns false while WebSecurity.Exists(username) does return true

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-membership

I have created WCF project along with MVC. I have implemented SimpleMembership database of default MVC template inorder to register and login user which I was able to implement successfully. However I could not query same database tables i.e. UserProfiels(UserId, UserName), webpages_Membership(UserId,Password, PasswordSalt,....) by using same WebSecurity.Login(UserName,Password) method.

Register Method in MVC Project is as

```
// Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);                   
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
```

WebSecurity.Login(username,password) method in WCF project is as follows

```
public string LoginService(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {

            string answer = null;
            if (WebSecurity.UserExists(UserName)) // returns true
            {
              if(WebSecurity.Login(UserName,Password)) // always return false
              {
                  string role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                  answer = role;

              }

            }
            return answer;



        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I wonder why WebSecurity.Login(UserName,Password) never populates the UserProfile and webpages_Membership table where username and corresponding password exists.

I have not updated any web.config file as it has default setting for db connection and WCF Rest binding which works perfectly.

I had a look here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx and searched on google but could not found the satisfactory solution.

Highly appreciate for any code snippet or suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're running the the MVC and WCF applications as separate sites, and that you are seeing the users appearing in the database.

By default, if you don't change anything else, ASP.NET will generate a distinct Application Name for each site (see [the remarks here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.applicationname(v=vs.111).aspx#Anchor_1)), and the users will partitioned by Application - this is probably why you can't log in with the user on the WCF site.

The [docs for `UserExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.userexists(v=vs.111).aspx) state:

> The method verifies that the user exists in the user profile table. However, it does not verify that a membership account exists for that user

It would appear that the profiles aren't being partitioned in the same way.

If you set the ApplicationName in the membership configuration, you'll be able to use the same database and logins on both applications.